# How can i declare return type in nestjs for Session User, in reques?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

```js
async authenticated(@Req()  request: Request) {
    const user = request.user

    return user
  }
```

user must globaly have rigth type.

in express passport i found

```js
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
        interface AuthInfo {}
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
        interface User {}
  }
}
```

how can i properly assign type to this interface in nestjs?

Comment: @MicaelLevi, it is related to nestjs and typescript, if you dont want to help, dont ruin my question, just move on.

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript you can type the function like so :

```
function add(x: number): string {
  return `The number is ${x}`;
}
```

The returned type on this example is the type `string`.

Find more example in [the official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#typing-the-function)